# matplotlib convert length of string to get coordinate units of fig.text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basic questions:

Is there a way to convert the length of a string to coordinate units as used in the arguments in fig.text? If so, how?

More info:
In attempting to use fig.text like this:

```
fig.text(0.54,0.909,'Title Starts Here', ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=12,color="black")

fig.text(0.7,0.909,'and Ends Here', ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=12,color="red")
```

I think it is possible to make getting the correct text coordinates easier in the case of trying to create a centered title with multiple instances of fig.text, like above.

I would like to do the following to achieve this using the coordinate system and the length of the strings, but that's where I'm stuck.

I believe the length of a character does not equal a unit of the length of a coordinate. But if I could somehow do the following, I think it would work:

1. figwidth = 1.0 (width available for entire title).
2. Get the length of the entire string to be plotted on one line of the title (i.e. strlen = len('Title Starts Here and Ends Here').
3. convert strlen to units of the coordinate system (strlenconv).
4. start = (figwidth/2) - (strlenconv/2) 
   -this tells me where to begin the first part of the text.
5. start + len('Title Starts Here ')(converted to coordinate units) 
   -this tells me where to start the second part of the text, note the extra space.

So, I think this can work if only I can get help with step 3.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you want to use `ha='center'`? What you're trying to achieve will be considerable simpler if you use `ha='right'` for the first and `ha='left'` for the second text artist.

Comment: I just realized that,  actually. So that will work, but I'm really interested in a solution for when I have more than 2 parts of text in one line.